# Giving and getting a discount

Tags: idioms, phrase-choice

Which one of the following sentences sound the most natural and the way natives say:

**a.** He gave me 10% off.
**b.** He gave me a 10% discount.
**c.** He gave me a discount of 10% discount.

---

And what about when we use *got* instead of *gave*:

**a.** I got 10% off.
**b.** I got a 10% discount.
**c.** I got a discount of 10% discount.

Comment: All of them are fine, except, in each case, (c) should only say _discount_ once: _I got a discount of 10%_.

Comment: Oh, sorry J.R. for the typo. But one more question. They do not make any semantic difference? Do they all mean exactly the same? Are they all used by natives?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point one:

One can get a discount of 10%. You don't need to repeat the word 'discount'. :)

The question:

There is no difference in meaning. The only difference at all is in the emphasis: 'getting a discount' doesn't talk about the person providing the discount, and focuses the emphasis on the fact that *you received one*. Noting that *he gave you a discount* brings emphasis to the provider.